# Assigning Values to the Array ipntr in ARPACK

Tags: fortran, arpack

I am trying to figure out how values are assigned to the array called ipntr, which stores pointers, in ARPACK. I am relatively new to fortran and I can't figure out exactly how the values of this array are initially set. The code I am looking at is an unsymmetric driver example dndrv1.f distributed with ARPACK and the portion I am not understanding is as follows

```
      program dndrv1 

      integer           maxn, maxnev, maxncv, ldv
      parameter         (maxn=256, maxnev=12, maxncv=30, ldv=maxn)
c
c     %--------------%
c     | Local Arrays |
c     %--------------%
c
      integer           iparam(11), ipntr(14)
      logical           select(maxncv)
      Double precision
     &                  ax(maxn), d(maxncv,3), resid(maxn), 
     &                  v(ldv,maxncv), workd(3*maxn), 
     &                  workev(3*maxncv), 
     &                  workl(3*maxncv*maxncv+6*maxncv)
c
c     %---------------%
c     | Local Scalars |
c     %---------------%
c
      character         bmat*1, which*2
      integer           ido, n, nx, nev, ncv, lworkl, info, j,
     &                  ierr, nconv, maxitr, ishfts, mode
      Double precision
     &                  tol, sigmar, sigmai
      logical           first, rvec
c
c     %------------%
c     | Parameters |
c     %------------%
c
      Double precision
     &                  zero
      parameter         (zero = 0.0D+0)
c
c     %-----------------------------%
c     | BLAS & LAPACK routines used |
c     %-----------------------------%
c
      Double precision
     &                  dlapy2, dnrm2
      external          dlapy2, dnrm2, daxpy
c
c     %--------------------%
c     | Intrinsic function |
c     %--------------------%
c
      intrinsic         abs

      write(*,*) ipntr
```

The result of the write statement is:

1606679396       32767  1606696480       32767  1606918048       32767           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0

Obviously there is nothing like ipntr(1) = 1606679396 so how have these values been assigned?

Thanks

Comment: I am currently also trying to figure out exactly what ipntr is used for but I think it's defined on the call to the first driver, below the code segment you've pasted. In my case that's: call znaupd ( ido, bmat, n, which, nev, tol, resid, ncv, v, ldv, iparam, ipntr, workd, workl, lworkl, rwork,info )

Answer (score 3):

If the variables aren't assigned anywhere, then their values will be determined by whatever random byte sequence happens to reside in memory. You should see that re-running the program will produce a different output sequence.